# php symfony error mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, composer-php

**I have problem with configuration MongoDB Symfony 
Program doesnt see class \MongoDbBudle\ to I went to Tools -> 
Composer -> add -> "doctrine/mongodb-odm". I tried to install it but I saw error:**

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe C:\Users\Root\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\composer.phar require doctrine/mongodb-odm:1.2.x-dev -n --no-progress
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Removal request for alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter == 1.1.9999999.9999999-dev
- Removal request for alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter == 9999999-dev
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.2.x-dev requires doctrine/mongodb ^1.4.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.4.0].
- doctrine/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> satisfiable by alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter[1.1.x-dev, dev-master].
- Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.2.x-dev].
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

**php.ini seems to be ok. I added dynamic extension mongo-dll:**
http://pastebin.com/bfb34A0s

**Please help me how to solve this problem.**

Comment: Hi user6949283, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I make a comment? Your question is quite difficult to understand, because it's quite difficult to read. Could you re-[edit] your question to improve the layout? The [help guide to markdown formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) might be useful to you.

Comment: Can you please show the output of `composer show -p`?

Comment: thanks for help, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ODM with PHP 7 is a bit trickier than it should, please check if adding

```
"provide": {
    "ext-mongo": "1.6.14"
}
```

to your project's `composer.json` would solve the issue. Otherwise you can see full chapter on how to use ODM with PHP 7 [in the official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/introduction.html#using-php-7)